# Does the solution to $x^i = 2$ have infinitely many solutions, or only one?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So in this video from bprp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chcwYQBOcRw (the second question so skip ~5 mins), he writes only one solution. However, in the comments, there is debate over whether there are infinitely many solutions or not. Can someone clarify this?
[image]
Haziq provides an interesting argument but Stranger 01 answers it. However, plugging the solution into wolfram alpha gives multiple solutions:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ei+%3D+2

Comment: How do you define $x^i$? Supposedly as $\exp(i\cdot\ln x)$. So, how do you define $\ln x$?

Comment: I thought that $i$ was simply just $√-1$? Yes,  $exp(⋅ln)$ also works.

Answer (score 4):

What is "$x^i$" in the first place? The most common meaning for that is $\exp(i\ln(x))$, since $\exp$ has a clear definition, and $\ln$ has a clear definition as the logarithm with a branch cut on the negative reals, and range in the strip between $\Im{z}=-\pi$ and $\Im{z}=\pi$.

*If* that is accepted, then
$$\begin{align}x^i&=2\\
\exp(i\ln(x))&=2\\
\ln\left(\exp(i\ln(x))\right)&=\ln2\\
\end{align}$$

Now be careful. For real $y$, $\ln(\exp(y))=y$. But for general complex $z$, $\ln(\exp(z))\neq z$. In general, $\ln(\exp(z))=z-2\pi i k$ for the right integer value of $k$ that lands $z-2\pi i k$ in that strip range of $\ln$.

$$\begin{align}
i\ln(x)-2\pi i k&=\ln2\\
i\ln(x)&=\ln2+2\pi i k\\
\ln(x)&=-i\ln2+2\pi k\\
\exp(\ln(x))&=\exp(-i\ln2+2\pi k)\\
x&=\exp(-i\ln2+2\pi k)=e^{2\pi k}\left(\cos\ln2-i\sin\ln2\right)
\end{align}$$

The logic shows that the only candidate solutions are these numbers $e^{2\pi k}\left(\cos\ln2-i\sin\ln2\right)$ as $k$ ranges over the solutions. But all these numbers are solutions, as you can verify:

$$\begin{align}
\exp(-i\ln2+2\pi k)^i&=\exp(i\ln(\exp(-i\ln2+2\pi k)))\\
&=\exp(i(-i\ln2+2\pi k-2\pi \ell i))
\end{align}$$

This is only for the right integer value of $\ell$. But the right value of $\ell$ is $0$, since $-i\ln2+2\pi k$ is already in the strip range of $\ln$.

$$\begin{align}
&=\exp(i(-i\ln2+2\pi k))\\
&=\exp(\ln2+2\pi ik)\\
&=\exp(\ln2)\exp(2\pi ik)\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

---

This was all based on *one* definition of "$x^i$" with *one* option for a logarithm function. Different things might happen with different choices.

Comment: Ok thank you. I see that this is where the confusion may have come from. I did not know there were multiple definitions of $i$, but just that $i = √-1$. Is there a *difference* between $i = √-1$ and $exp(⋅ln) = i$?? I understood all of your answer except for the last part where you introduced $l$. Where does there $l$ come from and why did you introduce it? To be clear, your answer **does** affirm that there are multiple solutions?

Comment: I didn't say that $\exp(i⋅\ln x) = i$. One definition for $x^i$ is $x^i=\exp(i⋅\ln x)$.

Comment: $\ell$ is explained in the paragraph discussing $\ln(\exp(z))=z-2\pi i k$. At that point in the discussion, "$k$" is being used for something else, so I just used a different letter to play that role.

Comment: This answer says there are infinitely many solutions under the assumptions about what $x^i$ really means, and that solutions are allowed to come from anywhere in $\mathbb{C}$.